# Keep App Awake on Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

Hey guys I had a question. I have a lightweight app (a metronome) which works really well on Wear, but the app is meant to run continually for a few minutes without user input. However, it goes to sleep periodically. A primary part of the app is the use of vibration, so the vibration stops once the app does.

I know Google is trying to enforce this wakelock, but are there any hacks that I can use to keep the app open and the vibrations constant for as long as I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Activity's layout XML, at the root node, add the keepScreenOn attribute. For example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">
```

Comment: There is an API for this now: http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on.html